# HTTP Route in Controller class called multiple times for Cordapp

Tags: java, spring, http, corda

I am seeing multiple invocations of the route /issue not sure why is the behaviors as such

```
    // initiate a flow using this route

    @GetMapping(value = "/issue", produces = TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    private String issue() throws FlowException {
        Party traderB = proxy.networkMapSnapshot().get(2).getLegalIdentities().get(0);

        proxy.startFlowDynamic(com.template.flows.IssueMetal.class,"Gold",10,traderB).toString();

        return proxy.registeredFlows().toString();
    }
```

and when I query the vault i see multiple unconsumed states whereas I should be only seeing one entry.

```
[StateAndRef(state=TransactionState(data=com.template.states.MetalState@3fa2279c, contract=com.template.contracts.TemplateContract, notary=O=Notary, L=London, C=GB, encumbrance=null, constraint=SignatureAttachmentConstraint(key=EC Public Key [4b:44:7c:7b:1b:38:a6:93:bd:9a:c4:1d:8b:46:b4:6b:77:ba:f8:0e]
            X: 38d226dcd0fa574316da478aa75225e6ce18f65cbd96e60bf3c8251b1965417
            Y: 56e5dcf7ccab21b712601ed0278501f2f33d0b5fdaa4c09e62639464e4910871
)), ref=45F75698C7D5FBE1AC0D88108C2C33F73567335168973B501B902312FA46ADBC(0)), StateAndRef(state=TransactionState(data=com.template.states.MetalState@3b9da4b0, contract=com.template.contracts.TemplateContract, notary=O=Notary, L=London, C=GB, encumbrance=null, constraint=SignatureAttachmentConstraint(key=EC Public Key [4b:44:7c:7b:1b:38:a6:93:bd:9a:c4:1d:8b:46:b4:6b:77:ba:f8:0e]
            X: 38d226dcd0fa574316da478aa75225e6ce18f65cbd96e60bf3c8251b1965417
            Y: 56e5dcf7ccab21b712601ed0278501f2f33d0b5fdaa4c09e62639464e4910871
)), ref=55E228CEA0F793068EC112978E584623211B869E647BD48DD6CB2211230D3205(0)), StateAndRef(state=TransactionState(data=com.template.states.MetalState@7e9f2da7, contract=com.template.contracts.TemplateContract, notary=O=Notary, L=London, C=GB, encumbrance=null, constraint=SignatureAttachmentConstraint(key=EC Public Key [4b:44:7c:7b:1b:38:a6:93:bd:9a:c4:1d:8b:46:b4:6b:77:ba:f8:0e]
            X: 38d226dcd0fa574316da478aa75225e6ce18f65cbd96e60bf3c8251b1965417
            Y: 56e5dcf7ccab21b712601ed0278501f2f33d0b5fdaa4c09e62639464e4910871
)), ref=912FD9296E430B6302B76DE0F6E25458D313D6F4E7AB29DDF80387F0099735FC(0))]
```

I have 4 nodes

TraderA, TraderB, Mint, Notary

This flow is being issued from Mint to TraderB.

Comment: Your REST endpoint is being triggered multiple times. How are you calling the endpoint?

Comment: I am just calling the endpoint from browser localhost:10050/endpoint. But now  I am using synchronized keyword in my function and don't see the behavior in chrome. However, safari shows multiple invocations.

Comment: Try using the web inspector to see if there are multiple requests fired

Answer (score 0):

I believe Ashutosh is correct. It would seem that your endpoint is being triggered multiple times, that's the only reason that you'd be seeing what you're seeing here.

If you're able to share more information about how you're running the flow that would help us figure out what's happening here.